# Reading information from a file in C language

Tags: c, file, document, fgetc

So I have the txt file from which I need to read the number of students written in that file, and because every student is in separate line, it means that I need to read the number of lines in that document. So I need to:

1. Print all lines from that document
2. Write the number of lines from that document.

So, I write this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* Argo[]){

    FILE *student;
    char brst[255];

    student = fopen("student.txt", "r");

    while(what kind of condition to put here?)
    {
        fgetc(brst, 255, (FILE*)student);
        printf("%s\n", brst);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ok, I understand that I can use the same loop for printing and calculating the number of lines, but I can't find any working rule to end the loop. Every rule I tried caused an endless loop. I tried `brst != EOF`, `brst != \0`.  So, it works fine and print all elements of the document fine, and then it start printing the last line of document without end. So any suggestions? I need to do this homework in C language, and I am using `VS 2012 C++` compiler.

Comment: Do you know the [`fgets` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c37dh6kf.aspx)? You can control a loop like this: `while(fgets(brst, sizeof brst, student) != NULL) { //... process }`

Comment: **while(fgets(brst, sizeof brst, student) != NULL) ** I used this as a rule, and now it printed every second line??

Comment: That is probably because your loop still contains its original char-by-char `fgetc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* Argo[]){
FILE *student;
char brst[255];
char* result = NULL;

  //Ensure file open works, if it doesn't quit
if ((student = fopen("student.txt", "r")) == NULL)
{
  printf("Failed to load file\n");
  return 1;
}

  //Read in the file
for ( (result = fgets( brst, sizeof(brst), student)); 
      !feof(student); 
      (result = fgets( brst, sizeof(brst), student)) )
{
  if ( result == NULL ) break; //I've worked on embedded systems where this actually ment waiting on data, not EOF, so a 'continue' would go here instead of break in that case
  printf("%s\n", brst);
}
fclose( student );
return 0;
}
```

feof() is only true after you've read past the end of the file.  Using a for with two identical reads, and feof() on the conditional is a simple way to ensure you read the file as expected.

Comment: But it is horrible way to go.

Comment: Weather, why is it horrible?  The code communicates the intentions clearly and is contained nicely.

Comment: I ran your code, and if the last line in the text file contains no `newline` ending, as it might not, the line is not displayed. Usually, one uses the `while(fgets(...) != NULL)` idiom without any `feof` malarky.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", brst);` relies on the last call to `fgets( brst, sizeof(brst), student)` to have _not_ messed up `brst` and that `fgetc()` works at least one.  That is not specified behavior.  Use the return value from `fgets()` rather than `feof()`  to detect when to finish the loop and do not rely on  data in `brst` after that failed call.  Code needs a modification.

Comment: Checking the fgets return value is important and I agree with that, I was in a hurry so I didn't add those.  I however disagree with only using the return value of fgets().  One of the embedded systems I worked on had an implementations of fgets() that return NULL to mean waiting on data, not end of file.  feof() always means end of file, thus why I use that.

Answer (score 1):

OP's code is close but needs to use `fgets()` rather than `fgetc()` and use the return value of `fgets()` to detect when to quit, it will be `NULL` [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40139500/reading-information-from-a-file-in-c-language/40140587#comment67549285_40139500).  Also add a line counter.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  FILE *student = fopen("student.txt", "r");
  unsigned line_count = 0;
  if (student) {
    char brst[255];

    //  fgetc(brst, 255, (FILE*)student);
    while (fgets(brst, sizeof brst, student)) {
      line_count++;
      printf("%u %s", line_count, brst);
    }
    fclose(student);
  }
  printf("Line Count %u\n", line_count);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DoktorD96 please notice that chux has not put any `\n` newline in the first `printf` statement within the loop. This is because `fgets` adds any `newline` it finds, at the end of the input string. If you are storing data you will not want any `newline` present and an easy way to remove it is with `brst [ strcspn(brst, "\r\n") ] = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Use feof() to check for an eof condition.
You are correctly reading the file line-by-line, but use fgets(), not fgetc() - and the cast is not needed.
Then use sscanf() to assign the line data to variables (or some "safe" form of it).

Comment: I am sorry, but [`feof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xssktc6e.aspx) does ***not*** check for an end of file condition. It is one if the most misused functions ever. Please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).